# Weird case of Non-alphanum char in element with leading alpha

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I got a weird case of "*Non-alphanum char in element with leading alpha*"

```
db.collection(u'clientsMap').document(tid).update({
  'clients.'+uid+'.status': True
})
```

I also tried:

```
db.collection(u'clientsMap').document(tid).update({
  f'clients.{uid}.status': True
})
```

For the 1st user id I get:

> *Non-alphanum char in element with leading alpha: a994f7df-47c5-4e8a-941e-2d080292694a*

But for the 2nd user id, *086aac5a-9087-40d1-b078-1273d5663067* it works with no issue, what am I missing?

For both of the users, I can use `.set({}, merge=True)`, and it works.

Do I need to do some kind of string sanitization, what could be the problem here?

Comment: `-` is not an alphanumeric character.

Comment: Notice the difference. The first userid begins with `a`, which is alphabetic, so it must be only alphanumeric. The second userid begins with `0`; since that's not alphabetic, there's no restriction on the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first user ID, `"a994f7df-47c5-4e8a-941e-2d080292694a"` begins with a non-alphanumeric character (a letter), whereas the second user ID, `"086aac5a-9087-40d1-b078-1273d5663067,"` starts with a numeric character.

To resolve this issue, you can ensure that the `uid` variable always starts with an alphanumeric character. One way to achieve this is by adding a valid alphanumeric character as a prefix if the `uid` starts with a non-alphanumeric character.

Here's an example in Python:

```
uid = 'a994f7df-47c5-4e8a-941e-2d080292694a'
if not uid[0].isalnum():
    uid = 'x' + uid  # Add a prefix if the first character is non-alphanumeric

db.collection(u'clientsMap').document(tid).update({
    'clients.' + uid + '.status': True
})
```

By appending the prefix `x` to the `uid` when it begins with a non-alphanumeric character, you ensure that it meets Firestore's requirements for field names.

Regarding the use of `.set({}, merge=True)`, it functions correctly because the `set()` operation does not depend on the field name format restrictions. The `merge=True` option enables you to update specific fields within a document without overwriting the entire document. Therefore, you won't encounter the same error when using `.set({}, merge=True)`.

For further details on field naming conventions and limitations, please refer to the Firestore documentation:

[Data model | Firestore | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/data-model)

[Field Paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#field_paths)

Comment: I am not sure why you attached those two documents, this case is not documented in any of them. Very weird decision on firestore keys.